# Frame rate conversion during playback for maximal smoothness

Tags: video, signal-processing

So I watch my 25 fps DVD on my 60Hz LCD monitor...  For now lets assume everything is progressive scan.

It seems that current DVD programs (and all media players on PC's, like youtube, vlc, etc.) just show the exact frames from the source video, and don't do any frame rate conversion.

Surely this leads to unnecessary jumpiness?  Some frames show for 2/60 seconds, while others show for 3/60 seconds?  The effect seems even more noticeable when the frame rate is close to the monitor refresh rate, such as 29 fps, where noticeable jumps can be seen every minute or so.

Are there any media players that use temporal interpolation through motion estimation to convert the frame rate during playback?  (like this:  http://compression.ru/video/frame_rate_conversion/index_en_frcn.html)

Comment: How does this question relate to AV _production_?

Comment: I figured playback was a primary consideration during production...

Is there a more relevant StackExchange site to post on?

Comment: Frame rate conversion is computationally demanding. That is why you can find it in hardware but not in software.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I think you are seeing is not because of the difference in framerate directly because this is inperceptable but how it is displayed.  You need to enable vsync to stop tearing and then it should play smoothly.